# Difference between two integers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need help with the following problem:

(1) The positive difference between a two digit integer and the integer created when the two digits are reversed is $27$. What is the positive difference of these two digits?

(2) The positive difference between a three digit integer and the integer created when the three digits are reversed in order is $297$. What is the positive difference of the hundreds digit and the units digit?

(3) The positive difference between a $4$ digit integer and the integer created when the thousands digit and the units digit are exchanged is $5994$. What is the positive difference of the thousands digit and the units digit? (You should begin to see a pattern here!)

**My Attempt** I tried setting variables equal to the tens place, units place, etc. But I keep on getting a Diophantine equation. Is that supposed to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the two-digit case:
$$\overline{ab}\to\overline{ba}$$
$$10a+b-10b-a=27$$
$$9(a-b)=27$$
$$a-b=3$$
So the required digit difference is 3. Now move on to the three-digit case:
$$\overline{abc}\to\overline{cba}$$
$$100a+10b+c-100c-10b-a=297$$
$$99(a-c)=297$$
$$a-c=3$$
The digit difference is still 3. Similarly, for the four-digit case (I'll leave the working out since you're supposed to see the pattern), the digit difference is $\frac{5994}{999}=6$.

Although the equations are Diophantine, nothing beyond fundamental symbolic manipulation is used.

Comment: Yes, I realized my problem. I, blindly, wrote $10(a-b)+b-a=27$ And did not see the possible factorization if I had written $-(a-b)$.

Answer (score 2):

(1) We are given $(10a+b)-(10b+a)=27$. The left hand side is $9(a-b)$, hence $a-b=3$.